# Calling up new Stack Overflow moderators from the 2011 election

Tags: discussion, moderators

Because we have a huge moderation load on Stack Overflow right now, I am recommending that we call up the 4th and 5th place finishers from the [2011 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1).

As you may recall from [the blog announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-our-new-trilogy-moderators-for-2011/), the winners were

[image]
[image]
[image]

We have contacted the 4th and 5th place 2011 election finishers and they have tentatively agreed to come on board as community moderators.

[image]
[image]

That is, [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) and [Kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev).

This is a courtesy notice to the community before it happens, so feel free to provide feedback!

Comment: Cavalry! WOO HOOOO!

Comment: When you refer to the "huge moderation load...right now", should that be taken to imply that these two additional moderators are being called up only *temporarily*? Or is this until the next elections are held?

Comment: @Cody That is a very good question, I saw nothing in the email asking me if I was still interested that it was a temporary post, but worth finding out!

Comment: @Cody Also, I didn't get the impression during the election that it was held to *replace* existing moderators, just *add* to them, please correct me if I am wrong, but I had the impression that the moderator post is "until removed", not until the next election. **And now I understand what you mean, your question is if this is a temporary post until the load decreases, or temporary post until the next election, or if this is a permanent promotion.**

Comment: @lasse whenever the community picks moderators, they are at-will until they no longer wish to be moderators. So it would be indefinite, and additive.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the clarification. You have my positive reply so I'll await the normal process on this then.

Comment: @jeff - I'm all good with this provided everyone else is happy.

Comment: Good call. Grats to our new moderators-to-be. May we have free beers? :D

Comment: +1, send in the troops, and give them a few free rounds of ammo :)

Comment: And I'm guessing that when Jeff says "at-will", he means fire at will :)

Comment: I appreciate being inform *before* something major like this happens.  Thank you Jeff.

Comment: @Benjol, let's not all pick on Will, eh? ;)

Comment: Let's go one more place! `:)`

Comment: Hooray, the King of Norway and the Republic of Ireland (or the Queen) are sending troops!

Comment: I was just about to complain that a new election should be held instead.

Comment: Ironically, the two runners-up have since stepped down, one was abduc— hired, and only one of the original winners remains.

Answer (score 11):

I have already answered the email which asked if i was still interested with a positive reply, I am definitely still interested in the role if I'm still wanted.

<strike>@Cody raises some pertinent points in his comment to the "question" though, so I'd like to just re-ask them here where I have more space.</strike>

Already answered by Jeff in comments:

> @lasse whenever the community picks moderators, they are [at-will](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment) until they no longer wish to be moderators. So it would be indefinite, and additive. – Jeff Atwood

<strike>Considering that the text of this question is "*Because we have a huge moderation load on Stack Overflow **right now***", my emphasis, is the promotion to a moderator intended as:</strike>

- A temporary promotion until the load decreases?
- A temporary promotion until the next normal election (in which case we would have the option of being re-nominated and running as normal)?
- A permanent promotion as though we had been elected during the last election?
- None of the above, but .... ?

Comment: Welcome to the team!

Answer (score 8):

No problem with doing this, however we need to also in the long term move load away from moderators so SO becomes more “self running”.

Is a “time and motion” study needed to see what moderators are spending their time on, and seeing if any of these tasks can be devolved to users or automated?

Comment: I can *guess* what moderators are spending their time on: **flags**. So along the lines of your proposal, letting 20K+ users help clean out the "Not An Answer" and "Low Quality" flag queues might be a good start.

Comment: I think it would be useful if the flags also affected /review, so those with sufficient rep can go in and use their regular powers to do things like: edit, vote to close, vote to delete, flag as spam. That way users can truly use their privileges in a way that aids the moderators (and everyone else).

Comment: The developers are already hard at work on a number of new algorithms, including bad quality question detection and duplicate posts detection.

Comment: @Cody: We moderators would still like to spot-check the "Not an Answer" flags.  You can help use out in a bigger way by *using your close votes!*  I still see a number of off-topic questions that still don't get enough close votes, even after 35 to 50 views.  Clearing "Not an Answer" flags is by far the easiest moderator task there is (I can handle about 12 per minute); it takes much more effort to evaluate questions for closing/migration/duplication.

Comment: @Robert: That's fair, I suppose. I just figured it was a menial task that could be handled by trusted users while still taking a load off the mods. I'd failed to account for how good you guys have gotten at it! And I agree about using close votes. One of the best changes made in a long time was increasing the daily allotment to 50. And on days when I'm active on the site, I'll use nearly all of mine, but I suppose that's not true of everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome aboard guys, and thanks for volunteering to help out.  It's good to see a couple of more international moderators, so flags don't continue to pile up while the rest of us are sleeping.

Answer (score 5):

Ya its a good proposal, as Stack Overflow is getting many items need to be moderated and load has been increasing day by day