# Is there a place where I can see information (chatrooms, Q&A, and results) for previous elections?

Tags: discussion, support, moderator-election

The text for all of the Stack Overflow elections appear to change retrospectively so that when one changes, e.g. to update the link to the "The candidates answer your questions" or the Election Chat Room, the link is changed for all the previous elections.

This makes getting information about previous elections difficult.

Is there a single place that contains information about all the previous elections?

Comment: This was inspired by the question [“The candidates answer your questions.”, different elections, same link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364780/1364007).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

All the elections use the same post, any changes to one affect all previous elections. [Jon Clements ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [provided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364780/the-candidates-answer-your-questions-different-elections-same-link/364781#comment566037_364780) in the comments to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364780/1364007) the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions) to the actual elections post.

---

**Some History**

What follows is (what I surmise) a brief history of the election pages:

- There have always been chat rooms where the candidates answer questions from the community (live).
- The "The candidates answer your questions" format (where a set list of questions are posted in a meta question, and every candidate answers the questions) was introduced in [Election 5](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) in February 2014. For elections 2-4, 'Town Hall' chat digests were created from the chat rooms which were created for the candidates to answer the community's questions.
- There were three rounds of additions to the moderator team in 2011 - elections [1 in January](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1) and [2 in November](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1), and the fourth- and fifth-place candidates from the January elections were [called up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287855/1364007) to be moderators in May 2011.
- The winners of elections are [calculated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77541/284827) using the [Meek STV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek) system. From [Election 4](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4) onwards, the results were [made available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170900/284827) on [OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/). After the results are announced the data for all elections can be downloaded from the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/{id}` and opened with OpenSTV for [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-openstv?os=pc) or [Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-openstv?os=mac).

---

**Elections, chat transcripts, and Q&A posts**

I've used the history of the [elections post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions) and some searches on meta to compile the following list:

## [Election 1](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1)   (2011-01-18 to 2011-02-02)

- [Town Hall](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/505/2011/1/28) (chat room)
- [Welcome Our New Trilogy Moderators for 2011!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/04/welcome-our-new-trilogy-moderators-for-2011)
- [Calling up new Stack Overflow moderators from the 2011 election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287855/1364007)
- [Election Data](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/1) (download link)

## [Election 2](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2)   (2011-11-07 to 2011-11-22)

- Revisions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/1) to [8](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/8) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [November 2011 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chats (scheduled)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111863/284827)
- [November 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest #1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112443/284827)
- [November 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest #2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112538/284827)
- [November 2011 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287870/1364007)
- [Election Data](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/2) (download link)

## [Election 3](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3)   (2012-06-04 to 2012-06-19)

- Revisions [10](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/10) to [12](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/12) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2012 Stack Overflow Moderator Election](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/12119/2012/6/4) (chat room)
- [June 2012 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136099/284827)
- [June 2012 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287867/1364007)
- [Election Data](https://stackoverflow.com/election/download-result/3) (download link)

## [Election 4](https://stackoverflow.com/election/4)   (2013-02-25 to 2013-03-12)

- Revisions [13](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/13) to [16](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/16) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2013 Stack Overflow Moderator Election](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/24975/2013/2/22) (chat room)
- [February 2013 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat Digest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170715/284827)
- [Spring 2013 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election Results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287864/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](http://www.opavote.org/results/967088/0)

## [Election 5](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5)   (2014-02-10 to 2014-02-25)

- Revisions [17](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/17) to [19](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/19) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2014 Stack Overflow Moderator Election](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/47184/2014/2/10) (chat room)
- [2014 SO Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299969/1364007)
- [February 2014 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250068/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](http://www.opavote.org/results/6524971895488512/0)

## [Election 6](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6)   (2015-04-06 to 2015-04-21)

- Revisions [20](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/20) to [21](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/21) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289449/1364007)
- [Stack Overflow 2015 Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/74583/2015/4/6) (chat room)
- [2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290096/1364007)
- [April 2015 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291017/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](http://www.opavote.org/results/4962933813542912/0)

## [Election 7](https://stackoverflow.com/election/7)   (2015-11-09 to 2015-11-24)

- Revisions [22](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/22) to [25](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/25) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [Fall 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309753/1364007)
- [Fall 2015 Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/94634/2015/11/9) (chat room)
- [Fall 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310356/1364007)
- [November 2015 Stack Overflow Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311045/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/6186395068530688/0)

## [Election 8](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8)   (2016-11-07 to 2016-11-22)

- Revisions [26](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/26) to [28](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/28) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2016 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337191/1364007)
- [2016 Stack Overflow Moderator Election](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/127571/2016/11/7) (chat room)
- [2016 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337571/1364007)
- [November 2016 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338289/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](http://www.opavote.org/results/6488198410665984/0)

## [Election 9](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9)   (2017-07-17 to 2017-08-01)

- Revisions [29](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/29) to [32](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/32) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351972/1364007)
- [2017 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/149409/2017/7/17) (chat room)
- [2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352386/1364007)
- [2017 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354232/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/5927932925050880/0)

## [Election 10](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10) (2018-03-12 to 2018-03-27)

- Revisions [33](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/33) to [34](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/34) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364152/1364007)
- [2018 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/166707/2018/3/12)
- [2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364498/1364007)
- [Spring 2018 Community Moderator Election RESULTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365198/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/5229219307061248/0)

## [Election 11](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11) (2019-03-04 to 2019-03-19)

- Revisions [35](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/35) to [37](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/37) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2019 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380600/1364007)
- [2019 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/189414/2019/3/4) (chat room)
- [2019 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380885/1364007)
- [2019 Community Moderator Election Results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381524/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/4853021517283328/0)

## [Election 12](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) (2020-07-06 to 2020-07-21)

- Revisions [38](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/38) to [50](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/50) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398884/1364007)
- [2020 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217027/2020-stack-overflow-moderator-election-chat) (chat room)
- [2020 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399106/1364007)
- [2020 Community Moderator Election Results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399609/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/5154305393819648/0)

## [Election 13](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13) (2021-10-18 to 2021-10-26)

- Revisions [55](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/55) to [58](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/58) of the Election page were active during this election.
- [2021 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411988/1364007)
- [2021 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/238039) (chat room)
- 2021 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire: integrated into [the nominations](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13?tab=nomination)
- [2021 Community Moderator Election Results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412566/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/5141741653983232)

## [Election 14](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14) (2022-11-07 to 2022-11-22)

- Revision [62](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/62) of the Election page was active during this election.
- [2022 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421213/1364007)
- [2022 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/249047) (chat room)
- 2022 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire: integrated into [the nominations](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14?tab=nomination)
- [2022 Community Moderator Election Results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421619/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/4819670275194880)

## [Election 15](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15) (2024-02-27 to 2024-03-13)

- Revision [62](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8041931/62) of the Election page was active during this election.
- [2024 Moderator Election Q&A – Question Collection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/428183/1364007)
- [2024 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256948/2024-stack-overflow-moderator-election-chat) (chat room)
- 2024 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire: integrated into [the nominations](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15?tab=nomination)
- [2024 Community Moderator Election Results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429467/1364007)
- [OpaVote Results](https://www.opavote.com/results/5843224907218944)

Comment: fyi, if you want to SEDE querying things, the date ranges can be helpful, since I don't think SEDE has dedicated info on elections. Ex. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1822275/2214692/, https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1822252