# Is there an advance notice for Stack Overflow Moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I'm curious.

I figured there are no fixed dates for Stack Overflow moderator elections and they are not even guaranteed to hold as an annual event. How do we know when an election is forthcoming? Is there an advance notice for the community before the whole process of nomination begins?

Comment: Rumours ... Gossip ... that is all the notice you'll get.

Comment: Maybe a *"20xx Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection"* if you're lucky

Comment: When they create a new election, then you'll see the corresponding meta post and if you're eligible to vote, then you'll also get a notification. So when you visit Meta regularly, then you won't miss it.

Comment: The [elections](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/revisions) post *may* be edited before other public notices of an impending election are announced. I'm not at my computer at the moment, so can't compare the revisions to the dates in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381115/1364007) but I think it was edited before an announcement was made.

Comment: There is rarely an advance notice for _anything_ happening to this site. Or we get an advance notice that x is about to happen, then 6-8 weeks later, y happens. At best you need to be in some minority, private VIP part of the community in order to get informed about anything.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

People interested in nominating for an election on SO generally have about two weeks to decide whether they wish to nominate - the week of question collection and the week of nominations. There are no official announcements prior to this two-week period, though there are ways to figure out if an election has been scheduled.

The system generally works as follows:

1. A decision is made to have an election and how many slots it should have - this usually is driven by the mods requesting it, though there have been times that the CMs propose it and it's accepted by the mods. In general, CMs do not force SO (or any site) to have an election.
2. A time is found for the election on the calendar - because holding an election requires CM oversight, we restrict the number that occur at any given time. We're currently scheduling them for the quarter during the last month of the preceding quarter, though we leave room for emergency election needs.
3. The election is scheduled in the system. At this point, the new election page is created with the incremented number. If you watch this page, you could theoretically know about the election in advance, assuming it was scheduled early.
4. The election "begins" when the question collection post is created, the week prior to nominations opening. This post is traditionally featured in the bulletin.
5. Nominations begin. Anyone who meets the criteria to nominate is sent a notification about the nominations being available (not actually certain we do this on SO, though).
6. Voting begins. Anyone with sufficient reputation to vote gets an inbox notification inviting them to do so.

For elections that have primaries, there's a step between 5 and 6 that notifies people to vote in the primary.

So, to answer your main question, there are several ways to know that there's an election coming but we generally don't publicly announce it until question collection begins. That said, once the election is scheduled, it's not expected to be a secret.

Comment: It's not enough notice. Considering that mods are "elected for life" rather than elected for a fixed term (which is something most users don't actually know), the whole election process and prior announcement should last much longer.

Answer (score 0):

There *may* not be any notice given to the general public, besides that of seeing a featured post on Meta Stack Overflow about the possibility of a future election.

Beyond that, you'll just have to wait.

Comment: Wouldn't that *be* the notice given to the general public, though? I mean, isn't a featured question/announcement on Meta the standard process by which we provide *any* sort of notice about site events to the general public?

Comment: It's not enough notice.

Answer (score -3):

In true Stack Overflow platform-with-capabilities-of-a-dead-dog fashion, there's no way to be notified about important events like this. The only way to know about them is to visit the site regularly and check the sidebar for Featured on Meta posts.

If you were bored enough, you could create an HTML scraper that hits the SO /questions endpoint and looks for the "Featured on Meta" box; if it finds it, it searches the links there for text containing the words "Moderator Election", and if it finds said text it notifies you. It would probably take 15 minutes to write as a script and you can then use your system task scheduler to run it daily.

Considering Stack Overflow's engineering team appears to be focused entirely on building "features" that nobody wants, as opposed to actually making their platform useful for users, that's about the best you can hope for.

Comment: Does your dog notify you of upcoming elections? Hmm, I guess mine must be broken. Or dead.

Comment: I think he was saying SO, like a dead dog, does not provide such notifications.  I do wonder if dead dogs change fonts, though.

Comment: You don't need to write a scraper. You can just go; [account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current) > Settings > [Email Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) > Inbox, and then select something other than "Off".