# 2024 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

[Moderator election #15](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15) on Stack Overflow has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Dalija Prasnikar]

[image: Stephen Ostermiller]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/15) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5843224907218944).

Comment: I did not win, but I guess the people who I expected to win were the winners, an they are respectable so I am satisfied with this outcome.

Comment: @CPlus Hope to see you in future elections!

Comment: Good luck to the new moderators.  We look forward to working with you.

Comment: Oh, starball lost to Dalija by a hair-thin margin.

Comment: Congrats both, very well deserved!

Comment: @VictorStafusa-BozoNaCadeia that's one way to see it. both Stephen and Dalija have my confidence and my appreciation. in that sense, this is also a win for me :)

Comment: @starball we'll see you in the blue room at some point I'm sure

Comment: I didn't end up paying attention to the election at all, but these are both familiar names who I am confident will make excellent additions to the team. @starball to be honest, I wouldn't have thought you'd be interested in the position, even if you'd also do well.

Comment: Finally, some good news to celebrate! And thanks to everyone who ran and everyone who voted.

Comment: @CPlus Maybe not winning was the real win! 

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I'll be back next election though.

Comment: Congrats both and can't wait to see the rest next elections!

Answer (score 123):

Me after handling my first pile of flags

[image]

[Image by Doc Searls](https://www.flickr.com/photos/docsearls/24422725502)

Comment: I liken moderation to becoming WALL-E, Pixar's animated recycling robot. You might be able only to compact a small amount of trash at a time, and the wasteland might be massive, but you still make a difference. I send both congratulations and commiserations 

Comment: My big congratulation to you!

Comment: congrats! don't worry about running out. I'll keep raising more for ya

Comment: Congratulations! Now excuse me while I go enjoy my free time.

Comment: Congrats @Stephen! :)

Answer (score 94):

Welcome fellows. We left a few flags for you

[image]

Comment: Oh, goodie... I'll have to do something about it ;)

Comment: Oh, new flag types.

Comment: there's a new "plagiarism" flag, for which chatgpt content could qualify, but problem with A.I. is that it's impossible to find the proper source.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The New York Times says it's them.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The source is "all of the above".

Comment: Since Other is seemingly piled with ChatGPT Crap, should duplicate answers be flagged as Plagiarized content, or just pile on in Other? Better, can there just be more descriptive flags, Such as A.I., Duplicate, Link-Only, etc.?

Comment: That's why I like modding on a small community. All the diamond, none of the heavy lifting.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Other, still.  Plagiarized content investigations are even slower than AI content investigations.  Really, the problem is that we need to get the AI flags out of Other.  We've had some tentative chats with CMs about it, but after the layoffs there hasn't been a lot of spare capacity to fix the problem.

Comment: problem is the A.I generated content is not going away. We have the old flags remaining (a few months old) but newcomers still think it's a good move to use A.I. to answer despite the numerous warnings (lol 10k+ link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78151773/6451573)

Answer (score 78):

Congratulations to both [Stephen Ostermiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1145388/stephen-ostermiller) and [Dalija Prasnikar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4267244/dalija-prasnikar)!

As usual, we've saved some flags for you:
[image]
<sub>Image is under CC BY 2.0, copyright Alan Levine, and has been edited. The original can be obtained from [pxhere.com](https://pxhere.com/en/photo/348762).</sub>

This year, we saved a particularly large number of flags:
[image]

Comment: Nice pile... there is still some blue sky left :)

Answer (score 76):

Welcome to the new mods. We all chipped in and got you each something nice for winning

[image: Giant Shovel]

Comment: the one with the helmet looks familiar!

Comment: This made me laugh out loud at work. Everyone looking at me now.